# Как можно узнать какие диски существуют?

Tags: python, linux, windows, disk

Как можно узнать какие диски существуют, то есть узнать их буквы всех существующих дисков, или имя всех существующих дисков если у человека Linux.
Нужно решение и под Windows и под Linux, на windows я нашел пару решений через win32api и psutil.windll, но хотелось бы найти код который будет работать и на Linux

Comment: Посмотреть содержимое /proc/partitions ?

Comment: Можно ещё /proc/mounts, держа в голове, что не всё, что смонтировано — диски, и не всё, что диски, смонтировано.

Comment: «То есть», не издевайтесь над языком. А вообще в Linux есть `lsblk`.

Comment: Что подразумевается под буквами дисков в линукс?

Comment: @Qwertiy думаю /proc/mounts, а что если лиск подключен не на букву, а в каталог на виндовс?)

Answer (score 1):

Если именно из питона, то пользуйте пакет [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil)

```
import psutil
psutil.disk_partitions()
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть практически в любом дистрибутиве Linux  программа `fdisk`. Базовый синтаксис команды выглядит следующим образом: `# fdisk [параметры] устройство`. Для вывода списка разделов жесткого диска достаточно использовать параметр `-l` и путь к файлу устройства этого жесткого диска. Для того, чтобы выяснить путь к файлу устройства жесткого диска может использоваться утилита `lsblk`.  В том случае, если нужно получить данные обо всех дисках, путь к файлу устройства диска может не использоваться:`# fdisk -l`. Если хотите использовать Python, то можно так:
`import os res = os.system('fdisk -l') print (res)`. Под  Windows(не пользуюсь со времен 7), если не изменяет память, тоже есть `fdisk` или аналоги.

Answer (score 0):

blkid
в никсах нет буквенного обозначения разделов, есть наименования девайсов и точки монтирования, куда они монтируются при использовании
в винде удобная утилита MiniTool Partition Wizard, и проверить, и потестить, и пофиксить